# How to do a loop for cards

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how do i do a loop for 10 cards? Cant find any solution anywhere.
I need it to output cards with some info which ill specify  later. I am new to React Native and got no idea what Im doing. It worked when ive written return into the loop, but it returned just one card (better than none  I guess).

```
 import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardContent, CardAction, CardButton, CardImage } from 'react-native-material-cards'

export default function Primary({ navigation })
{
    return(
        <ScrollView style=
            {{ 
                flex: 1,
            }}>
            <View>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                        Hlavni
                    </Text>
                <Text>Ahojda</Text>
            </View>    
            <Text>Swag</Text>
            <KartyLoop/>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}

const KartyLoop = () => {
    var swag[];
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {    
    <View>
    <Card style={{borderRadius: 25}}>

        <CardTitle 
            title="This is a title" 
            subtitle="This is subtitle"
        />
        <CardContent text="Your device will reboot in few seconds once successful, be patient meanwhile" />
        <CardAction 
            separator={true} 
            inColumn={false}>
            <CardButton
            onPress={() => {}}
            title="Push"
            color="blue"
            />
            <CardButton
            onPress={() => {}}
            title="Later"
            color="blue"
            />
        </CardAction>
        </Card>
        </View>
    }
    return();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When rendering a list of components in react native, you need to put them in some sort of list.

Try wrapping the code inside your `<View>` with `<Flatlist>`

Docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Full example from docs:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default App;
```